# Time it takes for a car to stop given a ratio of deceleration

Tags: sequences-and-series

My teacher put this question into an exam for series and sequences, I'm arguing that this is impractical because in reality a car wouldn't just instantly drop 6km/hr per second as a arithmetic series would suggest. Or drop a ratio of r as a geometric series would suggest.

Question: Cars A and B are travelling at 72km/hr next to each other, which car would stop first if car A decelerates at a ratio of 3/4 every second while car B would decelerate at 6km/hr every second

Using arithmetic series, I found out car B stops after 13 seconds, but using calculus it stops after 12 seconds (using acceleration -5/3, and starting velocity 20m/s)

Using limiting sum, and sum of arithmetic, I found out that car B has a breaking distance of 130m while car A 80m. But which car stops first? I stuck within the boundaries of the topic and subbed found out what velocity car A would be travelling at after 13 seconds, and it was ~2km/hr. So my answer was that car B would stop first, but I received 1 out of 4 marks for this question and my teacher said I didn't prove the time.

So I can tell my teacher this isn't a good question to put in a series and sequences exam, **can you use physics or any other method to work out how much time it takes for car A to stop?** Because I'm still in grade 10 and I can't learn physics at school yet

Comment: "A decelerates at a ratio of 3/4 every second": do you mean that on every second the speed decreases by 25% (and stays constant), following a geometric progression ? "B would decelerate at 6km/hr every second": do you mean that on every second the speed decreases by 6 km/hr (and stays constant), following an arithmetic progression ? These statements are unclear, please rephrase.

Comment: Yes that's what I'm trying to explain to my teacher, the question is very unclear.

let's go with what you said, going with the geometric progression approach creating a situation where the speed decreases and stays constant for the whole second. The other would be a arithmetic progression following instant speed change every second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Car A never stops moving, but it covers a finite distance that is shorter than car $B$. By the way, car $B$ travels a distance of $120$ meters, not $130$. Car $B$ covers a larger distance while braking, but it stops in a finite time. So the answer really depends on what "stopping first" really means.

As for your argument with the professor: If you want to solve *only* questions which are *completely* practical and *only* such that actually happen in reality, then you should really only solve problems from quantum physics and should go nowhere without Schroedinger's equation. After all, when you throw a ball, you never *really* throw a ball, you just change it's wave function sucht that the mean of it's distribution moves at some velocity relative to the earth's center.

What I am trying to point out is this:

**ALL REAL LIFE PROBLEMS ARE APPROXIMATIONS**. And you have to first learn how to solve simple approximations (like the approximation that a car's speed decreases by $6$km/hr per second, which, as far as approximations go, is not really that bad since the force on the car is pretty constant) before you can learn to understand very complex approximations (like quantum theory).

Comment: Wouldn't 13/2[40-[5/3][12]] = 130 m
while 0 = 400 -10s/3 would equate to 120m (physics)

How would I approach this question in a topic test then?

Comment: I have no idea how you got the number $130$, nor do I have any idea why the expression 13/2[40-[5/3][12]] would be the correct way of calculating the distance. I am sorry to say this, but your question will best be answered if you discuss it with the teacher.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of a geometric progression,
$$v=v_0r^t$$
$$e=v_0\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^t=\frac{v_0}{1-r}.$$

In the case of an arithmetic progression,

$$v=v_0-t\delta_v$$
$$e=\sum_{t=0}^{t=v_0/\delta_v}(v_0-t\delta_v)=v_0\frac{v_0}{\delta_v}-\frac12\frac{v_0}{\delta_v}(\frac{v_0}{\delta_v}+1)\delta_v=\frac{v_0}{2\delta_v}(v_0-\delta_v).$$

Comment: How would you work out the time? Instead of the distance?

Comment: This is done: $\infty$ and $v_0/\delta_v$.